# Regex To Find Names in All Caps

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a Regular Expression that I can use to find lines in a txt file that contain names in ALL CAPS using Notepad++ or similar tool.  Once I find a line that matches I want to add three line breaks.

I have various conditions since the lines are names.  Some of the names are only two characters.  Some have hyphens.  Some have multiple names. Some don't have spaces after their last name and comma.  Here are some examples:

- DOE, JOHN L
- DOE-SMITH, JOHN L
- DO, JO L
- DOE, JOHN BOB L
- DOE,JOHN L

I can run this in other programs as well.  Just trying to figure this out so I can get it finished.

**EDIT:** I was using [A-Z]+, [A-Z]+ but it didn't select the whole line and it didn't account for spaces and hyphens.

**ANSWER:** The following regex met my needs:

```
^(?!.*[a-z])(?!.*[0-9]).+$
```

**Part 2 ANSWER:** I also made an adjustment in order to do the second part of my request which was to add three line breaks ahead of the matched item.

```
^((?!.*[a-z\d]).+)$
```

I also made sure Match Case was selected.  It was using Regular Expression. and replaced with the following:

```
\n\n\n\1
```

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: Show your current regex!

Comment: Hi James, Please add your answer as an answer rather than editing your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead for a lowercase char:

```
^(?!.*[a-z]).+$
```

This matches "any line that doesn't contain a lowercase letter".

---

To also disallow numbers:

```
^(?!.*[a-z\d]).+$
```

Comment: This is working great, but I also have lines that only contain numbers, so I need to negate numbers.  So made a quick addition:

^(?!.*[a-z])(?!.*[0-9]).+$

And it's working like I want it!  Thanks.

Comment: Cool. See edited answer for simpler way to negate numbers too.

Comment: I didn't account for apostrophe's in a name like AL'JOHN.  Can I update this to include those as well?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "account for". They are already allowed. If you want to exclude apostrophes too, add `'` to the character class: `^(?!.*[a-z\d']).+$`. But if the list gets too long, maybe simpler to use a character class for what is *allowed* instead, like `^[A-Z -,]+$`.

Comment: If you're using this regex in Notepad++ or Atom, be sure to enable "Match Case" or it won't work right. I was convinced that both programs were buggy until I realized that this GUI option plays a role. It surprised me because I assumed this setting would be ignored when you're using a regular expression and it would purely use the regex, but if it's not set, both programs treat upper and lower-case the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Extended Regular Expressions with POSIX Character Classes

This will work for your provided corpus using GNU grep. Adapt to suit any changes to your data.

```
$ grep \
      --extended-regexp \
      --only-matching   \
      --regexp='[[:upper:]-]+, ?[[:upper:]]+' \
      /tmp/corpus 
DOE, JOHN
DOE-SMITH, JOHN
DO, JO
DOE, JOHN
DOE,JOHN
```

### Adding Newline Characters with GNU Sed

You can perform this operation with the append operation in GNU sed. For example:

```
$ sed \
      --regexp-extended '/[[:upper:]-]+, ?[[:upper:]]+/a\\n\n\n' \
      /tmp/corpus
DOE, JOHN L




DOE-SMITH, JOHN L




DO, JO L




DOE, JOHN BOB L




DOE,JOHN L
```